Yahoo Finamce での VMA (Variable Moving Average): 変動型移動平均の具体的な計算方法を知りたい
Yahoo Financeにトヨタ自動車の日足チャートを表示させています。
VMA(Variable Moving Average)というインジケーターが非常に有効であることがわかったからです。（リンクは ココ ）。左上の「Plots」のトグルボタンをOFF->ONするとVMAのラインが表示されます。
これを自分でも計算したいと思い、次のコードを作成しました。
VMAの重み付けの方法にもいくつかあるようで、次の4つを試してましたが、すべてYahoo Financeのチャートに表示されるもの（リンクは ココ ）とは異なります。
priceWeightFunction
volatilityWeightFunction
volumeWeightFunction
exponentialWeightFunction
Yahoo Finance USのチャートのVMAと同じ値がでる計算方法をご存知の方いらっしゃいますか？

ライブラリのインストール
> npm i fs
> npm i yahoo-finance2

コード
//import yahooFinance from 'yahoo-finance2';
//import fs from 'fs';
const yahooFinance = require('yahoo-finance2').default;
const fs = require('fs');

// Define the stock symbol and interval
const symbol = '7203.T';  // symbol(TOYOTA)
const interval = '1d';  // interval

// Function to fetch stock data
async function fetchStockData(symbol, interval) {
  try {
    const queryOptions = { period1: '2024-01-01', interval }; // adjust period1 as needed
    const result = await yahooFinance.historical(symbol, queryOptions);
    return result;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    return null;
  }
}

// Variable Moving Average calculation function
function variableMovingAverage(data, windowSize, weightFunction) {
  if (data.length < windowSize) {
    throw new Error('Data length must be greater than window size');
  }

  const vma = [];

  for (let i = 0; i <= data.length - windowSize; i++) {
    let weightedSum = 0;
    let weightSum = 0;

    for (let j = 0; j < windowSize; j++) {
      let dataPoint = data[i + j];
      let index = j;
      let alpha = 0.1
      const weight = weightFunction(dataPoint, index, alpha);  // Use the weight function
      weightedSum += dataPoint.close * weight;
      weightSum += weight;
    }

    vma.push({
      date: data[i + windowSize - 1].date,
      open: data[i + windowSize - 1].open,
      high: data[i + windowSize - 1].high,
      low: data[i + windowSize - 1].low,
      close: data[i + windowSize - 1].close,
      volume: data[i + windowSize - 1].volume,
      vma: weightedSum / weightSum,
    });
  }

  return vma;
}

// Example weight functions
function priceWeightFunction(dataPoint) {
  return dataPoint.close;
}

function volatilityWeightFunction(dataPoint) {
  return dataPoint.high - dataPoint.low;
}

function volumeWeightFunction(dataPoint) {
  return dataPoint.volume;
}

function exponentialWeightFunction(dataPoint, index, alpha = 0.1) {
  return Math.pow(1 - alpha, index);
}

// Main function
(async () => {
  const data = await fetchStockData(symbol, interval);

  if (!data) {
    console.error('Failed to fetch data');
    return;
  }

  // Define the window size
  const windowSize = 5;  // example: 12 periods

  // ★Choose a weight function
  const weightFunction = priceWeightFunction;
  //const weightFunction = volatilityWeightFunction;
  //const weightFunction = volumeWeightFunction;
  //const weightFunction = (dataPoint, index, alpha) => exponentialWeightFunction(dataPoint, index, alpha);

  // Calculate the Variable Moving Average
  const vmaResult = variableMovingAverage(data, windowSize, weightFunction);
  
  // Output
  let str = 'date\topen\thigh\tlow\tclose\tvolume\tvma\n'
  for (let i = 0; i < vmaResult.length; i++) {
    str +=
      vmaResult[i].date.toISOString().slice(0,10) + '\t'
      + Math.round(vmaResult[i].open * 100) / 100 + '\t'
      + Math.round(vmaResult[i].high * 100) / 100 + '\t'
      + Math.round(vmaResult[i].low * 100) / 100 + '\t'
      + Math.round(vmaResult[i].close * 100) / 100 + '\t'
      + vmaResult[i].volume + '\t'
      + Math.round(vmaResult[i].vma * 100) / 100 + '\n'
  }
  console.log(str);
  fs.writeFileSync('vma_result.tsv', str);
})();


Help for Yahoo Finance の Contact Us に質問をしてみてはどうでしょう？

kunif さん、ご回答ありがとうございます。Yahoo!に質問するのは思いつきませんでした。回答がもらえるかわかりませんが、頑張って英語で質問してみます！

質問してみましたが、「問題を特定できないのでスクリーンショットを送ってください」という見当違いの答えしか返ってきませんでした。あきらめることにします。自分が計算したVMAを使うことにします。ありがとうございました。
